# Is it possible to generate idl/bindings for non-Anchor programs

Tags: anchor, idl

As the title states is there a crate or any mechanism to get an idl similar to what we get with anchor programs but for vanilla/bare-bones solana programs ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, but afaik there is not automated solution yet, although I believe @acheron was working on something in that vein.

A few of them are implemented and available already:

- [associated token program](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/src/spl/associated-token.ts)
- [token program](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/src/spl/token.ts)
- [system program](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/src/native/system.ts)

There is actually an `#idl-all-the-things` channel in the Anchor Discord for that purpose.

The general idea of how to come up with it is to:

1. create a "shell" Anchor crate mirroring the structs and endpoints of the original program, like [here](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/custom-coder/programs/spl-token/src/lib.rs) (all currently IDL-ized vanilla programs are available [here](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/tree/master/tests/custom-coder/programs))
2. run the idl generation on it using `anchor idl parse`

Answer (score 1):

This [repo](https://github.com/acheroncrypto/native-to-anchor) might interest you. Using this you can generate IDLs for non-anchor-program.

Comment: a bit confused on how it works it seems it sometimes uses Shank but other wise it rewrites the instructions and adds comments, could you shed some light on how is it working ?

Comment: yes. please elaborate the answer here. this is effectively a "link-only" answer